# How to change the "selected" text to "bold / unbold" which is present in input tag "using html and JavaScript" only

Tags: javascript, html, css, frontend, web-deployment

I am trying to select a text/character from an input tag and when i press a bold button, selected text should change to bold and when the button is pressed again the selected text should change to normal.

here is my code but its not working.

```
<body>
<input type="text" name=inp id="inp">

<button onclick="getSelectedText();"><b>B</b></button>


<script>
    document.getElementsByTagName('input').mouseup(function(){
    getSelectedText().style.fontWeight="bold";
});

function getSelectedText() {
    if (window.getSelection) {
        return window.getSelection().toString();
    } else if (document.selection) {
        return document.selection.createRange().text;
    }
    return '';
}
</script>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i think: the function returns a string， it is not an element in the document and has no style attribute

Answer (score 0):

I think this is what you are trying to do.

```html
<input type="text" name=inp id="inp">

<button onclick="bold()"><b>B</b></button>

<script>
  function bold() {
    var inp = document.getElementById('inp');
    inp.style.fontWeight = inp.style.fontWeight == 'bold' ? 'normal' : 'bold';
  }
</script>
```